# Broke my Nexus 4 screen, is there a plug & play keyboard so I can unlock it?

Tags: lock-screens, screen, nexus-4, broken-screen, locked-out

I broke the screen on my Nexus 4 and it has a passcode for the lock screen.
Is there any way I can unlock it without fixing the screen, e.g. buying some sort plug & play keyboard for the micro-USB port?

Comment: not for nexus 4. but you can enter fastboot and boot into twrp from where you have full adb access (if bootloader was previously unlocked already)

Comment: Any way to get access to the data I have saved on the phone without fixing the screen?

Comment: with locked bootloader, maybe you can inject modified ROM (only system partition) with LG Flash Tool or LGUP, where adb root is enabled in /system/build.prop

Comment: Please also check LG Bridge software, it has backup option. Maybe you can restore backup after unlocking bootloader